# Jquery UI Touch Punch draggable and resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

i try make a web page for mobile with draggable and resizable box, i use jQuery and Touch Punch for mobile fixes.

On computer it's work fine, but in mobile browser work only resizable.

If i remove resizable then draggable fork fine.

If anyone has dealt with this problem please help, on the Internet, nothing could not be found.

this is example

```
http://jsfiddle.net /562y68bo/1/
```